# Bootstrap. Can't change navbar link color. Even with ID

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style my bootstrap navbar, but I can't change the color of the links. I've read that the bootstrap.css might be overriding my custom css file, so I prioritized the whole ul with an ID #menu_buttons. But the font color still won't change, although I can change it's size using font-size applied to this ID.
I've also tried changing it with .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
but still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Restart</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">


 </head>
 <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" height="40"</a>
  </div>
   <ul id="menu_buttons" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Регистрация</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Войти</a>      </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
   </body>
   </html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
background-color:#f3f9fe;

}

.navbar-brand {
 margin-top:-8px; 
}


#menu_buttons {
color:red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:red;
}
```

Comment: have you made it !important

Comment: Please provide working example and code

Comment: like this #menu_buttons {color:red !important}

Comment: @SantoshKhalse if he got it to work he wouldn't be here, would he?

Comment: g3mini@ my mean is source code

Comment: When your site is open press `F12`, inspect the navbar to see where it gets its color from, then copy & paste the entire class into your own `CSS` file and see what happens.

Comment: like this #menu_buttons * {color: red !important}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:red;
}
```

to this:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:red;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. But why didn't it work with ID? Doesn't this element have the highest priority?

Comment: It would work if you put it in `#menu_buttons > li > a`